# How do I set a system environment variable in Windows XP without using the "My Computer" Dialog

Tags: windows

I'm switching between different Java SDKs (1.4.2, 1.5.0 and 1.6.0) for various projects.  I would like to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable on my Windows XP machine without going through the tedious My Computer -> Advanced -> [Select System Variable] -> Edit -> Ok -> Ok

Is it possible to do this from the command line, or is there a utility that can do this?

(Note that I am not referring to the standard batch file "SET" command - I want to set the environment variable "globally," not just for the life of a console window).

Comment: While I agree that your question might be of interest to programmers, I still don't think it is programming related. It is an OS question not a programming question. It is entirely possible that someone will disagree with me and re-open the question.

Comment: hell yes this is "programming related" or do you not know what SDK stands for?

Comment: Disagree on not programming related. See the answer from Patrick who has actually written a program to solve the problem. And actually there is no built-in Windows OS functionality to solve it ;-)

Comment: And my understanding is that the OP was asking for a way to do it without writing the program that Patrick provided. He explicitly asks for a command line or a utility to do it. He implicitly asks for a non-programatic method.

Comment: Strongly disagree on non programming related too. Project deployment issues such as execution environment are very much programming related. Please reopen.

Comment: Dude, do you seriously not understand the difference between a programming question, a programming RELATED question and a NON programming related question.  This question isn't a programming question, but it is a programming RELATED question.

Comment: Ok,rant time.  I hate hypocritical "closers". How in the world do make sense of closing this one, but cheerfully answer questions about "developer must haves" with "I need to control my own light."

Comment: Mainly because I didn't have close priveleges then. Regardless, I will happily bow to peer pressure in this case.

Comment: re-worded the question to clarify its relation to programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm:

> Using the add-on tool Setx.exe
>
> It is not part of the standard Windows
>   XP setup but a command-line tool
>   called setx.exe is included in the
>   [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en). This tool extends the set
>   command so that permanent changes in
>   the environment variables can be made.
>   For example, to add a folder C:\New
>   Folder to the path, the command would
>   be setx path "%PATH%;C:\New Folder"

Answer (score 1):

[Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) has a tool called "setx.exe" that can do what you are looking for. setx path "%PATH%;C:\New Folder"

[Source](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some VBScript I use for this:

```
set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colSystemEnvVars = objShell.Environment("System")
Set colUserEnvVars = objShell.Environment("User")

' Parse args
select case args.Count
case 0, 1, 2
    help
case 3
    sVariable = args(0)
    sValue = args(1)
    sScope = UCase(args(2))
    sMode = ""
case 4
    sVariable = args(0)
    sValue = args(1)
    sScope = UCase(args(2))
    sMode = UCase(args(3))
end select

select case sScope
    case "S"
        if sMode = "A" then
            sValue = colSystemEnvVars(sVariable) & sValue
        end if
        colSystemEnvVars(sVariable) = sValue
    case "U"
        if sMode = "A" then
            sValue = colUserEnvVars(sVariable) & sValue
        end if
        colUserEnvVars(sVariable) = sValue
    case else
        help
end select

WScript.Quit

'******************************************************************************
Sub help()
    WScript.Echo ""
    WScript.Echo "Create or update an environment variable."
    WScript.Echo ""
    WScript.Echo "usage:"
    WScript.Echo "======"  
    WScript.Echo "cscript SetVar.vbs variable value {S|U} [A]"
    WScript.Echo ""
    WScript.Echo "eg:"
    WScript.Echo "==="     
    WScript.Echo "cscript SetVar.vbs MYVAR 'Hello world' U"
    WScript.Echo "cscript SetVar.vbs PATH 'C:\MyPath' S A"

    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

The scope can be 'S'ystem or 'U'ser. The last argument, 'A', if present, appends the value to the existing value of the variable (useful for adding a directoy to the PATH system variable).

The variables will presist, but you'll have to close then re-open a console to use them. I usually run this from the "Run..." dialog, then open a console.